# Bootstrap menubar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to use bootstrap navigation in my SharePoint 2013 site.  The navigation needs to have staggered unordered lists/list items.  I have a good start on the layout but the javascript is messing me up...whenever I click one of the links the nav box closes every time and resets.  This is what I am using so far.  I am using bootstrap 3.3.6.  I am not the greatest with JS but slowly learning.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent about 20 hours on this one thing.

```
<div id="menubar" class="menubar-inverse animate">
    <div class="menubar-fixed-panel">
        <div class="expanded">

            <a href="/">
                        <span class="text-lg text-bold "></span>
                    </a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="menubar-scroll-panel">
        <div style="display:block;">
            <a class="btn btn-icon-toggle menubar-toggle right-toggle" data-toggle="menubar" href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars" style="color:white" title="this icon expands and collapses left navigation"></i>
                    </a>
        </div>
        <ul id="main-menu" class="list gui-controls">
            <li id="svc_menuitem" role="menuitem">
                <a href="/sites/1VERC/PM-Guidebook/" title="Welcome">
                    <div class="gui-icon">
                        <!--<i class="fa fa-bookmark" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="Welcome"></i>-->
                    </div>
                    <span class="title" title="Welcome">
                        Welcome</span>
                </a>
                <ul id="main-menu" class="list gui-controls">
                    <li id="other_menu" role="menuitem">
                        <a href="" title="PM Guidebook: Welcome & Overview">
                            <div class="gui-icon">
                                <!--<i class="fa fa-file" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="PM Guidebook: Welcome & Overview"></i>-->
                            </div>
                            <span class="title" title="PM Guidebook: Welcome & Overview">
                        PM Guidebook: Welcome & Overview</span>
                        </a>

                        <ul id="main-menu" class="list gui-controls">
                            <li id="other_menu1" role="menuitem">
                                <a href="" title="What is a Project?">
                                    <div class="gui-icon">
                                        <!--<i class="fa fa-book" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="What is a Project?"></i>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="title" title="What is a Project?">
                        What is a Project?</span>
                                </a>
                                <li id="other_menu2" role="menuitem">
                                    <a href="" title="Project Management">
                                        <div class="gui-icon">
                                            <!--<i class="fa fa-book" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="Project Management"></i>-->
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="title" title="Project Management">
                        Project Management</span>
                                    </a>

                                    <li id="other_menu2" role="menuitem">
                                        <a href="" title="Project Management">
                                            <div class="gui-icon">
                                                <!--<i class="fa fa-book" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="Starting a Project within OSI|VERC"></i>-->
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="title" title="Starting a Project within OSI|VERC">
                        Starting a Project within OSI|VERC</span>
                                        </a>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="main-menu" class="list gui-controls">
                    <li id="other_menu3" role="menuitem">
                        <a href="" title="PM Guidebook: Charter">
                            <div class="gui-icon">
                                <!--<i class="fa fa-file" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="PM Guidebook: Welcome & Overview"></i>-->
                            </div>
                            <span class="title" title="PM Guidebook: Charter">
                        PM Guidebook: Charter</span>
                        </a>

                        <ul id="main-menu" class="list gui-controls">
                            <li id="other_menu4" role="menuitem">
                                <a href="" title="What is a Project?">
                                    <div class="gui-icon">
                                        <!--<i class="fa fa-book" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="What is a Project?"></i>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="title" title="What is a Project?">
                        Project Purpose</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="other_menu5" role="menuitem">
                                <a href="" title="Project Management">
                                    <div class="gui-icon">
                                        <!--<i class="fa fa-book" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="Project Management"></i>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="title" title="Project Management">
                        Project Team</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li id="other_menu6" role="menuitem">
                                <a href="" title="Project Management">
                                    <div class="gui-icon">
                                        <!--<i class="fa fa-book" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="Starting a Project within OSI|VERC"></i>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="title" title="Starting a Project within OSI|VERC">
                        Charter Expiration & Approval</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="main-menu" class="list gui-controls">
                    <li id="other_menu3" role="menuitem">
                        <a href="" title="PM Guidebook: Charter">
                            <div class="gui-icon">
                                <!--<i class="fa fa-file" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="PM Guidebook: Welcome & Overview"></i>-->
                            </div>
                            <span class="title" title="PM Guidebook: Charter">
                        PM Guidebook: Charter</span>
                        </a>

                        <ul id="main-menu" class="list gui-controls">
                            <li id="other_menu4" role="menuitem">
                                <a href="" title="What is a Project?">
                                    <div class="gui-icon">
                                        <!--<i class="fa fa-book" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="What is a Project?"></i>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="title" title="What is a Project?">
                        Project Purpose</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="other_menu5" role="menuitem">
                                <a href="" title="Project Management">
                                    <div class="gui-icon">
                                        <!--<i class="fa fa-book" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="Project Management"></i>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="title" title="Project Management">
                        Project Team</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li id="other_menu6" role="menuitem">
                                <a href="" title="Project Management">
                                    <div class="gui-icon">
                                        <!--<i class="fa fa-book" style="color:white; margin-left:5px;" title="Starting a Project within OSI|VERC"></i>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="title" title="Starting a Project within OSI|VERC">
                        Charter Expiration & Approval</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you i would use some PNP (sharepoint community) work, re using a master page that already integrates bootstrap.

[link here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UI.Responsive)